# Merging two json key value paris into a new key value pair in Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

So just based on some feedback I've expanded the code a bit, as I'm actually taking a larger csv and transforming it first. What I'm trying to output is actually the transformation - relevant code:

```
def doThings(infile, outfile):
    f = pd.read_csv(infile)
    hmCols = {"timestamp": [], "value": []}    
for i, row in f.iterrows():
    total = row["Playspace_1"] + row["Playspace_2"] + row["Playspace_3"] + row["Playspace_4"]
    hmCols["timestamp"].append(row["Timestamp"])
    hmCols["value"].append(total)


pd.DataFrame(hmCols).to_json(outfile, orient="records")
doThings("test.csv", "heatmapData.json")
```

Right now it outputs as:

`[{"timestamp":1417982808063,"value":1},{"timestamp":1417982808063,"value":1},{"timestamp":1417982808753,"value":1},{"timestamp":1417982811944,"value":1}...]`

What I need is for it to be like:

`[{"1417982808063":1},{"1417982808063":1},{"1417982808753":1},{"1417982811944":1}...]`

Any help on how to do this transformation would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry that was just a dumb typo - fixed

Comment: are you using pandas for any particular reason here?

Comment: Honestly - we were going to originally do visualizations with it (heatmaps) - but for a lot of reasons we're now going to use D3... I'm not necessarily wedded to at this point

Comment: is this some file that is periodically generated? or generated every time you submit a request to the URL endpoint?

Comment: It's old data and I'm pulling it from log files. So it's generated every time I submit a request - this isn't live

Answer (score 0):

... just use a `csv.reader`

```
  f = csv.reader(some_file_handle)
  next(f) #skip header
  json.dump(dict((row[0],sum(map(int,row[1:]))) for row in f),open("output.json","wb"))
```

I think at least ... without testing

this assumes `in_file.csv` looks something like

```
timestamp,Playspace_1,Playspace_2,Playspace_3,Playspace_4
123      ,0          ,1          ,0          ,0
....
```

(I undeleted this answer based on your comment on the original question)

if you were really married to pandas I guess you could do something like

```
totals = f["Playspace_1"] + f["Playspace_2"] + f["Playspace_3"] + f["Playspace_4"]
json.dump(dict(zip(f["timestamp"],totals),open("out.json","wb")))
```

Comment: whoops had a typo was missing parentheses

Comment: I would also recommend using a cache mechanism like memcache to store your results so it only recalculates if there is a change to the input file...

Answer (score 0):

```
dic_in = [
    {"timestamp":1417982808063,"value":1},
    {"timestamp":1417982808063,"value":1},
    {"timestamp":1417982808753,"value":1},
    {"timestamp":1417982811944,"value":1}
]

dic_out = [{i['timestamp']: i['value']} for i in dic_in]
```

Comment: When I try this I get the error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str`

Comment: @Mike What is your version of Python?

Comment: I tried it like this `f = pd.DataFrame(hmCols).to_json(orient = "records")

 dic_out = [{i['timestamp']: i['value']} for i in f]
 print dic_out`

and as: `dic_out = [{i['timestamp']: i['value']} for i in hmCols]
 print dic_out` but in both cases got the TypeError